# Dynamics CRM Online : missing required components

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamic-programming, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I’m working with MS dynamics online. I have created a Lookup field “contact” in the page division then I create in Contact page a sub-grid of page division. In my solution, I have both contact and division.  I publish all the customization then when I export the solution I get the message:

> missing required components Les composants suivants manquent dans
>   votre solution. L’importation échouera si ces composants n’existent
>   pas déjà dans l’organisation Microsoft Dynamics CRM cible. Pour
>   ajouter les composants manquants à votre solution, annulez
>   l’importation, ouvrez la solution et cliquez sur le bouton Ajouter les
>   composants nécessaires.

[View screen capture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KDU3.jpg)

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the solution, click your "Division" entity from the Components list and click `Add Required Components`, it should add whatever is missing and causing that warning to appear